# Add vertical line to plotly express charts to show last observations

Tags: python, plotly, facet

Using this textbook example, could anyone please advise how do you add a vertical line per chart to show the last observation. Can use fig.add_vline if the number was constant but I need it to be dynamic.

px.histogram(data_frame = diamonds,x= 'price',facet_col = 'cut')

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by last observed value? The following code can be used to simply draw a vertical line on a faceted graph. `fig.add_vline(x=10000, line_width=1, line_dash='solid', line_color='red')`

Comment: Hi, thanks. So the last observation in each column I want to show as a straight line on their individual chart so you can see where the current observation is on the chart. The last entry of each column is variable and so they line needs to correspond to that columns last observation.

Comment: What does it mean to be the last observed value in a histogram?

Comment: Hi thanks. So a histogram will be based off the data in the column/variable in the dataframe. The last observation of the first column would be df.column[0].tail(1). I want this on the actual histogram so we can see the current level on the distribution of levels.

Comment: To add a line uniformly in the EXPRESS subplot, we can use the comment method, but since the final line of data for each individual subplot is likely to be different, the only way to do this is to create it in a graph object.

Answer (score 0):

Your next question gave me a new insight: in express, you said that individual vertical lines cannot be drawn in a faceted graph, but I stand corrected. We take the data for each degree of cut of the diamond, get its final price, and designate that as the value of the vertical line. The diamond data is taken from the Seaborn dataset.

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

diamonds = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
fig = px.histogram(data_frame=diamonds, x='price', facet_col='cut')

for c,idx in zip(diamonds['cut'].unique(),[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]):
    df = diamonds[diamonds['cut'] == c]
    print(c, df['price'].tail(1).values[0])
    fig.add_vline(x=df['price'].tail(1).values[0], line_width=1, line_dash='solid', line_color='red', row=idx[0], col=idx[1])

fig.show()

Ideal 2757
Premium 2757
Good 2757
Very Good 2757
Fair 2747
```

[image]